# How drivers on developers PC affect build

Tags: c#, drivers, ftdi

I am developing a GUI for a custom USB device. Unfortunately, I don't have a physical copy of that device so I have to mock everything during the development process. Everything is fine - for me.
Also this solution has a setup project that has to install proper drivers.

On my machine that setup project fails to install drivers and saying that I have to plug the device first.

That's not a big deal but when that GUI is run on the PC with a proper device plugged in - it cant find the drivers neither! And this happening only when I am trying to run the application compiled on my machine. When i am trying to run the application compiled on the PC with the actual drivers installed - everything is fine.

How the environment affects the compilation process? How can I compile my app on my PC (without drivers installed) that it will run on other PCs correctly?

Comment: Since we don't know anything about your application, it's going to be difficult to answer this.

Comment: Which information about this app can help? It is a simple WPF app that using FTDI drivers to communicate with a usb device. Setup project is a WiX project

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not necessary to have the same device drivers on the build machine that are required for the application to run.

An exception would be if there is something more than just device drivers that get installed. For instance, tools and binaries necessary to access an API for the device might be installed along with the device drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But can you explain then why the app compiled on my machine is not working on a test machine while as app compiled on that test PC works there fine? If the issue is with some additional binaries then the same app should not work anyway...

Comment: You didn't include any of the information that would be required to answer your question.